# Python how to save xlsx to pdf with selected area

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I trying to save one excel sheet to pdf like that [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTDjv.png), but I getting this [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h04Pk.png). In Excel file this area is selected [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO9bp.png). If I'm saving as pdf directly from Excel it's going well(1st pic), but from python it's not(2nd pic).

I'have tried many solutions and libraries, but I didn't find right.
There is one of them:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open("example.xlsx")

sht = wb.sheets['Banner']
sht.to_pdf("example")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the paper and page size like:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open("example.xlsx")

sht = wb.sheets['Banner']

# Set the page orientation to portrait
sht.page_setup.orientation = xw.constants.PageOrientation.portrait

# Set the paper size to A4
sht.page_setup.paper_size = xw.constants.PaperSize.a4

# Fit the worksheet to one page wide and tall
sht.page_setup.fit_to = (1, 1)

# Export the worksheet as a PDF
sht.to_pdf("example.pdf")

# Close the workbook and the Excel application
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Documentation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open("example.xlsx")

sht.page_setup.print_area = '$A$1:$AO$91'

sht = wb.sheets['Banner']
sht.to_pdf("example")
```

I found it.
I just selected print area manually in code and it's work fine